# Google Play Game Services Leaderboars - show only certain leaderboards

Tags: google-play-services

My game will have 2 modes - hard and normal. At the end of a game I would like to show different sets of leaderboards depending on the mode - not just all the leaderboards. For example, I would show only hard mode leaderboards or only normal mode leaderboards. Is this possible? I only see a method to show all leaderboards.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest extending the BaseGameActivity. That makes using the game services kind of easy.

To show all leaderboards use:

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getAllLeaderboardsIntent(getApiClient()), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

**To show only one of your leaderboards, you can simply use:**

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```

See [Leaderboards in Android - Displaying a leaderboard](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/leaderboards).

The request code REQUEST_LEADERBOARD is an arbitrary integer that you define by yourself.
In the developer console's game services section, you can easily export your leaderboard ids as xml files using the provided button.

Comment: Yea, I want to show a subset of the leaderboards - not all or just one.

Comment: I'm already know you can show one leaderboard or all leaderboards. I'm trying to show some of the leaderboards. Unfortunately I think the answer is it's not possible =(.

Comment: Ok, now I understand your problem. Probably, there is no method to do that directly. You could design a custom layout similar to Google's leaderboard selection and then show single leaderboards using the given getLeaderboardIntent-method.